# Check box change background icons in Android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have looking for posts that would help me in implementing a custom check box.I have a checkbox for determining whether its a favourite or not and using two different custom icons for displaying the state.I have used small int as datatype(0 or 1) to determine whether favourite or not.I have tried using onclicklistener as well as oncheckchangelistener,but no luck.

This is my drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important_holo_dark" android:state_checked="true"/>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important_holo_dark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item  android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important_holo_dark" />
    <!-- <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important"/>     -->
</selector>
```

This the checkbox code..

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/is_favourite_check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/email_img_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email_img_button"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector" />
```

And this is the implemented code in fragment.

```
is_Favourite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (((CheckBox) buttonView).isChecked()) 
        {
            int result=mContactsManager.updateInfo(info.getId(), 1);
            Log.d("Test", "Result is "+result +" ie is favourite");

        } else {

            int result=mContactsManager.updateInfo(info.getId(), 0);
            Log.d("Test", "Result is "+result +" ie not a favourite");
        }
    }
```

when its 1 I tried setting it to chkbox.setchecked(true) and if 0 to chkbox.setchecked(false).But this doesnt seem to be working.Any mistakes in my logic?? Plz do help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the java code? Please post related code.

Comment: how you are applying this to checkbox?

Comment: updated the post with it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this selector .

if I put **drawable** wrong then please change it.

it's work in my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important_holo_dark" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important_holo_dark" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important" />

    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important" />

    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important_holo_dark" />

</selector>
```

Comment: You did use the setchecked(boolean) method to set the state of the checkbox manually..didnt you??..I did use setchecked(boolean) but doesnt seem to be working..

Comment: i did not use setchecked(boolean) method

Comment: @AndroidMech  when you call setchecked(boolean)?
are change valu of boolean variable?

Comment: no i dont change any values..I am just fetching them from sqlite..and set it true or false..

Comment: then how it's change?
when your boolean variable is not change then your checkbox not change state every time.

Comment: then please select my answer as perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important_holo_dark" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_important"/>

</selector>
```

Set this drawable as button for checkbox and try.Let me know whether your problem solved or not.

Comment: Sorry..it isnt working..the ic_action_important is a grey star while the ic_action_important_holo_dark is a white star..After i do chkbox.setchecked(true), it should have shown the white star,but still shows the grey star..

Comment: Add your check box layout and code with your question

Comment: Remove android:clickable="true" from layout and use the above drawable for button.

Answer (score 0):

use this -

```
<CheckBox 
  ...
 android:button="@drawable/your_drawable_xml
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

Few months back i faced same problem, but finally i found a simple and sweet solution, you have to use two different drawable images one to indicate checked and second to indicate unchecked !

**CustomCheckboxActivity.java**

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomCheckboxActivity extends Activity {
    private CheckBox checkBox1;
      private CheckBox checkBox2;

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        checkBox1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                  public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(checkBox1.isChecked()==true && checkBox2.isChecked()){
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkBox1.getText()+"  "+checkBox2.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else if (checkBox1.isChecked()==true){
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkBox1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                              }
                        else if(checkBox2.isChecked()==true){
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkBox2.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                  }
            });

    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<CheckBox
android:text="  OptionOne"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox
android:text="  OptionTwo"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</CheckBox>
<Button
android:text="Button"
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

To customize checkbox, create an xml file in drawable folder
**res/drawable/custom_checkbox.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
 android:state_checked="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked"/>
 <item
 android:state_checked="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked" />
```

[image: Checked]

[image: Unchecked]

[image: Finally, resultant image]

Answer (score 0):

Add to CheckBox `android:button="@drawable/your_drawable_xml"`